# What's the best way to regex replace a string in python but keep its case?

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to replace instances of a string in python but keep their original case.

For example, say I was replacing the strings 'eggs' with 'bananas':

`This recipe requires eggs.` --> `This recipe requires bananas.`

`Eggs are good for breakfast.` --> `Bananas are good for breakfast.`

`I'M YELLING ABOUT EGGS!` --> `I'M YELLING ABOUT BANANAS!`

Right now, I do an re.compile and .sub but I can't figure out a smart way without explicitly declaring the three variants each time. I'm replacing about 100+ words so I imagine there has to be a smarter, more pythonic way.

EDIT: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF A PREVIOUSLY ASKED QUESTION. --> Some differences: I'm replacing the word with an entirely different word, not wrapping it in  tags. Also, I need to keep the case even if its all caps, etc.. Please do not mark as duplicate without fully reading the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key insight here is that you can pass a function to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to do all sorts of checks before determining the proper replacement for a given match. Also, use the `re.I` flag to get all the cases.

```
import re
def replace_keep_case(word, replacement, text):
    def func(match):
        g = match.group()
        if g.islower(): return replacement.lower()
        if g.istitle(): return replacement.title()
        if g.isupper(): return replacement.upper()
        return replacement      
    return re.sub(word, func, text, flags=re.I)
    # return re.compile(word, re.I).sub(func, text) # prior to Python 2.7
```

Example:

```
>>> text = "Eggs with eggs, bacon and spam are good for breakfast... EGGS!"
>>> replace_keep_case("eggs", "spam", text)
"Spam with spam, bacon and spam are good for breakfast... SPAM!"
```